# Why split button dropdown hides options behind the cell?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

i have added a column to have bootstrap split button dropdown in jqGrid grid. This is a react component and code as follows:

**The React code:**

```
    "use strict";

var EmployeeGrid = React.createClass({
    displayName: "EmployeeGrid",

    componentDidMount: function componentDidMount() {
        this.loadGrid();
    },
    loadGrid: function loadGrid() {
        var $grid = $("#list"),
            resizeGrid = function resizeGrid() {
            var newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
            $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
        };
        $(window).on("resize", function () {
            resizeGrid();
        });

        var $body = $('body');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'sample.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function success(data1) {
                var d1 = data1;
                console.log('hello');
                $("#list").jqGrid({
                    data: d1,
                    colNames: ["id", "FirstName", "LastName", "Country", "Status"],
                    colModel: [{ name: "id", align: "center", hidden: true },
                        { name: "FirstName", align: "center", sortable: false, hidden: false },
                        { name: "LastName", align: "center", sortable: false, hidden: false },
                        { name: "Country", align: "center", sortable: false, hidden: false },
                        { name: "Status",
                        align: "center",
                        width: 93,
                        sortable: false,
                        edittype: 'select',
                        hidden: false,
                        editoptions: { value: { '1': 'Hired', '2': 'Extended', '3': 'Terminated',
                                '4': 'Fired', '5': 'Retired' }, defaultValue: 'Hired' },
                        formatoptions: { disabled: false },
                        formatter: function formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

                            var str = '<div class="btn-group"> ' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="min-width: 65px;max-width: 65px">Action</button>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">' + '<span class="caret"></span>' + '<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>' + '</button>' + '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">' + '<li><a href="#">Hired</a></li>' + '<li><a href="#">Extended</a></li>' + '<li><a href="#">Terminated</a></li>' + '<li><a href="#">Retired</a></li>' + '</ul>' + '</div>';

                            return str;
                        } }],
                    loadComplete: function() {//chaneg the height of each row to 200
                        var grid = $("#list");
                        var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                            grid.jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i], false, { height : 200 });
                        }
                    },
                    cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
                    autoResizing: { compact: true, resetWidthOrg: true },
                    autowidth: true,
                    height: 350,
                    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                    guiStyle: "bootstrap",
                    pager: '#pager',
                    caption: 'Employees Listing',
                    pgbuttons: false,
                    viewrecords: false,
                    pgtext: "",
                    pginput: false

                });
            },
            error: function error(x,y,z) {
                //alert('DATA CANNOT READ'+ JSON.stringify(x));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
            }
        });
    },
    render: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                React.createElement(
                    "h1",
                    null,
                    "Top header"
                )
            ),
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                React.createElement(
                    "div",
                    { className: "container-fluid" },
                    React.createElement("table", { id: "list" }),
                    React.createElement("div", { id: "pager" })
                )
            ),
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                React.createElement(
                    "h1",
                    null,
                    "bottom header"
                )
            )
        );
    }
});


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// this code will show the seleted text on the button
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$('.btn-success').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchor = $(e.currentTarget);
    var href = anchor.attr('href');
    var text = anchor.text();
    var button = anchor.closest('.btn-group').find('button:first-child');
    button.attr('data-url', href);
    button.text(text);
    button.on('click', gotoUrl);
});
function gotoUrl(e){
    e.preventDefault();

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////


ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(EmployeeGrid, null), document.getElementById('divOuterContainer'));
```

**The HTML:**

**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
    <style>
        .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow > td {
            white-space: normal;
        }
        /****************************************/
        .ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-caption,
        .ui-jqdialog.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqdialog-titlebar {
            background-color: #009926;
            color: white;
        }
        .ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {
            background-color: #009926;
            color:#fff;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .ui-jqgrid-bootstrap.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager,
        .ui-jqgrid-bootstrap.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager {
            background-color: #009926;
            color:#fff;
        }
        .table > thead > tr > td.active,
        .table > tbody > tr > td.active,
        .table > thead > tr > th.active,
        .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.active,
        .ui-jqgrid-actions .ui-pg-div.active {
            background-color: #009926;
        }
        /*fixes split buttons breaking when page resizes*/
        .btn-group {
            white-space: nowrap;
            font-size: 0;
        }
        .btn-group-vertical>.btn, .btn-group>.btn {
            display:inline-block;
            float:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divOuterContainer" class="container-fluid"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="EmployeeGrid.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**

in the above code stack overflow wont let me add facebook's react libraries. So please when you test the code add react files ie: **react-15.0.0.js** and **react-dom-15.0.0.js**

**The JSON data it uses**

```
[{"id":1, "FirstName":"John","LastName":"Akram", "Country":"USA", "Status":"Hired"},
  {"id":2, "FirstName":"John","LastName":"Akram", "Country":"USA", "Status":"Hired"},
  {"id":3, "FirstName":"John","LastName":"Akram", "Country":"USA", "Status":"Hired"}
]
```

it generates the following grid:

[image]

**Question # 1:**
As you can see in code i have added four options for teh split button

1. Hired
2. Extended
3. Terminated
4. Retired

but as you can see in the image it shows only three options, why it hides the last option "Retired" inside the cell and how do i fix this?

**Question #2:**

[image]

As you can see the user selects options but the selected option wont show on button. but i have written code for it, if you see the react code at bottom of the grid's code

```
$('.btn-success').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchor = $(e.currentTarget);
    var href = anchor.attr('href');
    var text = anchor.text();
    var button = anchor.closest('.btn-group').find('button:first-child');
    button.attr('data-url', href);
    button.text(text);
    button.on('click', gotoUrl);
});
function gotoUrl(e){
    e.preventDefault();

}
```

But why it wont set selected option text as the text of the button? How do i fix this?

Comment: The `z-index` property specifies the stack order of an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
tr.jqgrow:hover {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

If displaying it correctly on `:hover` is not enough, consider adding a class to the row on dropdown open and removing it on close:

```
$(this).closest('tr.jqgrow').addClass('opened');
```

... that needs to go into the open event of your dropdown. And needs to be removed on dropdown close event. And, of course, adjust the CSS above to `tr.jqgrow.opened {...}`

Another thing to check for is if any of the `.dropdown` parents has an `overflow:hidden` and override it with `visible`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the problem still exists : (

Comment: In that case you need to create a **runnable, inspectable** [mcve] of your problem here, using the output markup of your react and the actual CSS applying. Can't help you much without it. It's also possible you have an `overflow:hidden` on the cell. Without looking into it, I really can't tell.

Comment: overflow:hidden fixed the issue  : ) thanks please add to answer so i can give points

Comment: @Dore.Ad Glad I could help you. Is it possible that this overflow is added by `hidden: true` in your `colModel`? Try removing it and you might not need the override. Happy coding!

Comment: @ Andrei Gheorghiu  for the dropdown column i have set hidden:false in colModel